# obtaining the Google maps API v2 key in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm a Computer Science graduate student and have recently taken up android development. I want to build an app for my college that would locate the nearby hangout joints on the Google map. I did a lot of surfing and found the source codes here as well as at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112044/GPSLocator-App-to-Find-Current-Nearest-Location-us. But since I'm working on API 17, I'm required to obtain an API key, the steps for which I found at    this(above) link. I also checked https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key for the necessary steps, but being a novice I really couldn't understand some of it. Could you please walk me through the entire process in detail?

Comment: -header is not more related with your question and you can find more of instruction how to get apikey from stackoverflow

Comment: The header has been rectified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fine i'll give some step by step instruction with windows operating system

step 1

open your java installed deprecatory my deractory is

```
C:\Program Files\Java
```

and open `jdk1.7.0_13 > bin` you shoud have `keytool.exe` inside of  bin folder

step 2

open your command line application(enter cmd your run)

enter cd

```
cd  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin
```

step 3

find your android keytool path if you using eclipd you can find path using

`window > preference > android > build` (you can find keytool pathor you can create new one)

step 4

switch your command line again and use

```
keytool.exe -v -list alias androiddebugkey -keystore "<your android debug key path>"
```

and enter password if you have give password when you create bebug key and coppy your SHA1 KEY

step 5

use this url to access goole api console and crate new project and enable  ect from services and

from API Access create new android key and

enter

then you can get api key

i'll attach some of screen shot 
[image: my command line]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To set up for android development refer this link:
http://geeklabs.co.in/android/Setup4ADE.html

To add ADT Plug-in in Eclipse:
http://geeklabs.co.in/android/ADTplugin.html

To create your own API key follow this link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#obtaining_an_api_key

Here change the api key with your key in manifest file and follow these steps:
and make sure that your google_play_services_lib project should be present in your project's work space and make it as library and add it to your poject.

Manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.geeklabs.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="replace with your API key"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.geeklabs.map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

After got this let me know.